# In Netbeans the program runs smoothly, in command line I get a JavaNoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

I have developed a big program in Java and Csound that has worked smoothly until now. 
In the last days I decided to add a "info" menu to display infos about the developer. 
This infos were showed in another frame that i have created in Netbeans; I open it using `setVisible(true)`.

The strange behavior is that in Netbeans everything work without problems, in command line everything works except the info Frame.

Obviusly, the class exists and works.

Any ideas?

So here is the exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> userInterface/info/InfoFrame
>     at userinterface.MainFrame.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:380)
> ```
>
> [snip]

Answer (score 3):

The class *exists* sure, but not in the classpath when you run from the command line. Ensure that the jar exists in the classpath on the command line. Netbeans does this magic behind the scenes for you.

Comment: The strange thing is that the class is packaged with the Jar, like the other classes! This is my launch script: `java -jar MusicaParlata2.jar ` . The class is IN this jar. In the manifest file of this Jar there is a Class-Path declaration: `Class-Path: lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar lib/tritonus_share.jar lib/vorbisspi1.0.3.jar lib/csnd.jar lib/DKnob.jar lib/jdom-1.1.2.jar lib/RangeSlider.jar` and these libs are outside the MusicaParlata2.jar file.